# How to get max of two columns?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, assuming you have a table with three columns like these:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MY_TABLE 
(
    ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    ANSWERED_ON TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) NOT NULL,
    COMMENTED_ON TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)
);
```

And you want to know the last time a record had any activity (in this example either being answered or commented on counts), How do you go about querying the `ID` and whichever of the two date columns (`ANSWERED_ON` or `COMMENTED_ON`) is greater?

I tried using the `MAX` function —knowing it was a long shot— like so:

```sql
SELECT MAX(ANSWERED_ON, COMMENTED_ON)
```

...but of course it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest way is `GREATEST`(assuming both columns are non-nullable):

```
SELECT *, GREATEST(ANSWERED_ON, COMMENTED_ON) AS max_date
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Otherwise nullable columns have to be handled:

```
SELECT *, 
  GREATEST(ANSWERED_ON, COALESCE(COMMENTED_ON, '1970-01-01'::DATE)) AS max_date
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `IFF` (`if-then-else`) function.
The [Snowflake docs on this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff) state:

> Single-level `if-then-else` expression. Similar to CASE, but only allows a single condition.
> If `<condition>` evaluates to `TRUE`, returns `<expr1>`, otherwise returns `<expr2>`.

So it's possible to use it like this.

```sql
select
    ID,
    iff(ANSWERED_ON >= COMMENTED_ON, ANSWERED_ON, COMMENTED_ON) LAST_ACTIVITY
from MY_TABLE
```